# How to debug why my Python program is not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def solve(numLegs,numHeads):
for numChicks in range(0, numHeads + 1):
numPigs = numHeads - numChicks
totLegs = 4*numPigs + 2*numChicks
if totLegs == numLegs:
return(numPigs,numChicks)
return(None,None)

def barnYard():
heads = input('Enter a Number of heads')
legs  = input('Enter a Number of legs')
pigs,chickens = solve(legs,heads)
if pigs == None:
    print ('There is no solution')
else:
    print ('number of Pigs',pigs)
    print ('number of chickens',chickens)

print (barnYard())
```

I am getting error in 3 places in this code; can someone help me figure out why it is giving errors?

Comment: What are those places? What is your error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: You'll need to fix your indentation before this will get much of anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The main error is that Whitespace is essential in Python. You must maintain correct indentation.

Your function definitions need to be indented, as do for loops and if statements.

`returns` are statements that need to be followed by whitespace before the item they are to return. (doing a `return(x)` would try to call a defined `return` function instead of running the correct return statement)

Another error is that when you accept a variable from input, it comes in as a string. If you want to use it for math as an integer, you need to cast it with `int(input("your prompt"))`

Another error is that you are using commas to join a string to another variable, and on top of that it's not a string. Make them strings, then use the `+` operator to contact them in the print statement.

```
def solve(numLegs,numHeads):
    for numChicks in range(0, numHeads + 1):
        numPigs = numHeads - numChicks
        totLegs = 4*numPigs + 2*numChicks
        if totLegs == numLegs:
            return (numPigs,numChicks)
        return (None,None)

def barnYard():
    heads = int(input('Enter a Number of heads'))
    legs  = int(input('Enter a Number of legs'))
    pigs,chickens = solve(legs,heads)
    if pigs == None:
        print ('There is no solution')
    else:
        print ('number of Pigs ' + str(pigs))
        print ('number of chickens ' + str(chickens))

print (barnYard())
```